# Why is the User information stored in two different tables in ASP.NET's default Membership Provider?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

There are two tables: aspnet_users and aspnet_membership. Can anyone elaborate on the reasons why they don't use a single table for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The membership table holds information related to the **MembershipProvider** API interface.  The users table stores usernames and user ids, which are referenced from many providers.

- Users

  - Membership (MembershipProvider)
  - Profile (ProfileProvider)
  - Roles (RoleManager)
  - etc

The aspnetdb system is very modular and each piece can be customized through the various providers.  The tables need to be separated so each interface can be rewritten, redirected, etc.

Comment: I was hoping someone with a clue would chime in ;o)

Comment: Thanks :)  The modularity is actually really nice, I have a project that implements a custom MembershipProvider and a custom RoleManager and it was pretty easy.

Comment: Ahem. The aspnet_Users table is re-used in several providers. The aspnet_Membership table is actually only for use with the membership provider as I already mentioned.

Comment: If you are logged in through some other authentication mechanism,  the aspnet_Users table still gets a record.

Comment: Dave: that doesn't contradict what I said, the membership table is just for the MembershipProvider.  I'll edit the post to try and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other providers in ASP.NET (other than the Membership provider) also store user-specific information. e.g. Profile.

More information about this:

Several of the shipped ASP.NET providers store/use information in the context of a user name.
One of these is **MembershipProvider**, which provides an authentication store and set of services.

Another is **ProfileProvider**, which allows user-specific data to be held against each user.

You can still use **ProfileProvider** regardless of whether or not you have chosen to use **MembershipProvider**.
Because **ProfileProvider** must store data against a user name (i.e. as exposed by the `Context.User.Identity.Name` property), it will go ahead and add a user record into aspnet_Users.

Hopefully this clarifies the reason for the separation.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it doesn't make much sense to me either.  It seems as though the aspnet_Membership table was set up to house user/Application level information but UserID is a PK.  Very strange.  Perhaps there were setting themselves up for a situation where you do have multiple applications per user in some later release.

Dave mentions that there are other tables like aspnet_Profile that hold user specific info.  It could be that the ASP.NET 2.0 folks were just trying to separate out different groupings of fields into more easily digestible chunks.

I know it's just a bunch of conjecture.  Hopefully someone with some actual knowledge will chime in.

Answer (score 0):

I found this explination from this [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx):

The SqlMembershipProvider stores user account information in two related tables:

- aspnet_Users - has a record for each user account, storing the bare essentials. The UserId column uniquely identifies each user in the system, and is stored as a uniqueidentifier (a GUID).
- aspnet_Membership - has a UserId column that ties each record back to a particular record in aspnet_Users. The aspnet_Membership table stores core data associated with every user account: Email, Password, the security question and answer, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The `aspnet_users` contains the users you create (authentication FORMS) ... NOTE THET when your authentication is set to WINDOWS, the users are WINDOWS users e.g. domain\firstname.lastname

The `aspnet_membership` contains membership preference information used in stuff like `WebPart`s and user settings

Answer (score 0):

The aspnet_users table contains information for all users : anonymous and not anonymous. The aspnet_membership table contains information about register users (no anonymous).